# Flutter: Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'. > Keystore file not set for signing config release

Tags: android, flutter, keystore, signing

Working on a Flutter app and I have tried all of the fixes listed on here previously and nothing has worked. I believe everything is configured correctly and in the correct places, so I need help figuring out why the signing config is still throwing this error. I have been trying for hours to find another solution with no luck. Everything is spelled correctly too. The error is below.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file not set for signing config release
```

The `key.properties` folder is in the main android folder, and the `upload-keystore.jks` file is within `android/app`.

key.properties is

```
storePassword=xxxx
keyPassword=xxxx
keyAlias=upload
storeFile=/Users/..../android/app/upload-keystore.jks
```

And full `build.gadle` is

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Services plugin

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.fytfeed.fytfeed"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Well after a day of banging my head against the wall I figured this one out. I had an unknown space in my `key.properties` folder at the beginning of the file name that was throwing the error. So if everything checks out, be on the lookout for random spaces!

Answer (score 2):

- Regenerate the key

> OR

Open the project "/android" in Android studio

- **Build** -> **Generate Signed Bundle / APK ..**
- Complete the steps...

Answer (score 1):

just select your proper path of JKS file in key.properties and re run

Answer (score 0):

After sometime I realize that I am not using the same computer and the path in key.properties might be different, in this case I am using Linux instead macbook, so the path is different, I changed to Linux path and it worked